# SQL Server 2012 Evaluation database to SQL Server 2012 Express?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2012-express

I have taken over a client, who had an inhouse developer. The inhouse developer used SQL Server 2012 Evaluation (which I believe/assume is Enterprise)?

Regardless, their SQL Server eval has now expired, and they are "locked" into buying SQL Server, as their whole app infrastructure now sits in SQL Server 2012.

Will the database of an evaluation version of SQL Server, spool up in a SQL Server 2012 Express version?

I don't right now have the architecture at hand to test this scenario, and would like some ideas around the best way to resolve this. As it is now, they are dead in the water.

The client does not need anything specific to 2012 Standard or enterprise version for that matter (to my knowledge), and they are only about 30 users, using the app inhouse.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As long as the `.mdf` file size is less than 10 GB, and no Enterprise-only features were used, then there should be no problem to use this database with SQL Server 2012 Express

Comment: Cant mark your comment as the answer? Seems to have worked a charm, thanks.

Comment: @marc_s , Please add your comment as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Can't do that, since the question is marked as "closed"

Comment: Ahh, missed that. Sorry. Just doing some housekeeping :-)